# How to detect Chinese Character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-workbench, chinese-locale

I need to calculate the number of Chinese in a list of columns.  For Example, if "北京实业" occur, this is four characters in Chinese but I only count once since it occurs in the column.

Is there any specific code to figure this out?

Comment: *"this is four characters in Chinese but I only count once"* – Sorry, what?

Comment: @deceze there are some columns in the table, once Chinese character happen, which means Chinese character happen once, so I count once.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*(E[2-9F]|F0A)'
```

will count the number of record with Chinese characters in column `col`.

Problems:

- I am not sure what ranges of hex represent Chinese.
- The test *may* include Korean and Japanese.  ("CJK")
- In MySQL 4-byte Chinese characters need `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`.

**Elaboration**

I am assuming the column in the table is `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  In utf8 encoding, Chinese characters begin with a byte between hex E2 and E9, or EF, or F0.  Those starting with hex E will be 3 bytes long, but I am not checking the length; the F0 ones will be 4 bytes.

The regexp starts with `^(..)*`, meaning "from the start of the string (`^`), locate 0 or more (`*`) 2-character (`..`) values.  After that should be either `E`-something or `F0A`.  After that, anything can occur.  The E-something is, more specifically, `E` followed by any of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or F.

Picked at random, I see that `草` encodes as the 3 hex bytes `E88D89`, and  encodes as the 4 hex bytes `F0A09C8E`.

I do not know of a better way to check a string for a specific language.

As you found, the REGEXP can be rather slow.

This regexp could be over-kill, in that some non-Chinese characters may be captured.

Comment: I try it and shows the error: "Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: Try it on a smaller table.  That error means that you timed out.  You may need to run the query over chunks of the table.

Comment: That is great answer, I will be appreciate if you can explain what is the meaning of REXGEXP, and why to use that?

Comment: I elaborated in my answer.