# Character encoding and decoding in Python with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, ascii, latin

For query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
```

MySQL Database returns:

```
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   latin1
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/mysql-5.7.27-macos10.14-x86_64/share/charsets/
```

In my Python script:

```
conn = get_database_connection()
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='latin1')
```

For one of the columns that has following value:

```
N’a pas
```

Python returns:

```
N?a pas
```

Between N and a, There is a star shaped question-mark. How do I read it as is? What's the best way to handle it? I have been reading about converting my db to `utf-8` but that seems like a long shot with a good chance of breaking other things. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

At some of the places in code, I have done :

```
value = value.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

to handle `utf-8` data like accented characters but `apostrophe` did not get handled with the same and I ended up with `?` instead of `'`

Comment: (1) The "fancy" apostrophe `’` (right single quotation mark, U+2019) is not part of Latin-1. Upgrading to UTF-8 is definitely the best option. It's 2020 now, UTF-8 is everywhere. (2) There are very rare cases where `value.encode('utf8', 'ignore').decode('utf8')` has an effect. Typographic quotes are none of them. 99.9% of the time, this expression returns the original `value` unchanged.

Comment: @lenz - UTF-8 would be better.  However, the comment is incorrect.  Hex 92 is the latin1 encoding of 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK'.

Comment: @RickJames It depends how you define "Latin-1". Code point 0x92 is a control character in standard Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1). It is a quotation mark in the Windows codepage 1252 (among others), which is a modification of the former and which is colloquially referred to as "Windows Latin 1". I don't know how MySQL defines "Latin-1"; I wouldn't be surprised if it's the latter.

Comment: @lenz - I think that MySQL's latin1 does nothing to validate bytes that it receives.  Utf8, on the other hand, squawks at virtually any latin1 string with an 8-bit character, including the 92 in question.

Comment: @RickJames This is also true. There's no good way to validate any 8-bit encoding, unless you know what the interpreted string should look like.

Comment: @lenz - "validate" -- Do you mean "see if there are any utf-8 characters in the string".  Or "Verify that all 8-bit codes are valid utf-8 codes".  Or something else.  Meanwhile, I think I have seen some techniques with some libraries (don't know about python).

Comment: @RickJames Given a sequence of bytes, you can check if it is valid UTF-8. If you think some text was stored in UTF-8, this validation will most certainly tell you if this assumption is right. But if the text was stored in an 8-bit encoding like Latin-1, a validation like this is pointless, because any sequence of bytes is valid. Anyway, I'd love to continue this discussion with you, but I fear it's driving us away from the OP's question.

Comment: @lenz - Storing utf8 bytes in a latin1 column is mostly OK.  However, sorting and comparisons are broken because the individual bytes will be compared.  This is called "double-encoding" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @lenz - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061775/how-to-detect-chinese-character-in-mysql shows how to check for specifically Chinese.  I think I provided a different REGEXP for someone looking for just Arabic.  I can pretty easily conjure up similar code for any other language.  I think I have a Perl script that will discover whether a file has non-utf8 8-bit codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the database to UTF-8 is better for the long run, but risky because you  may break other things like you say. What you can do is change the database *connection* encoding to UTF-8. That way you get UTF-8 encoded strings out of the database, without having changed how the data is actually stored.

```
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf8')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf8')
```

If that seems too risky, but you could consider having two separate database connections, the original and one in `utf8`, and migrate the app to using `utf8` little by little, as you have time to test.

If even that seems too risky, maybe try using a character encoding that's more similar to mysql's version of latin1. MySQL's "latin1" is actually an extended version of [cp1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which itself is a Microsoft extension of the "standard latin1" that's used in Python (among others).

```
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='cp1252')
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='cp1252')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any form of encoding/decoding; it only complicates your code and hides more errors.  In fact, you may be trying to "make two wrongs make a right".

Go with utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Notes on "question mark":  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)
Notes on Python:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python